# Why Is Laravel Giving Me This Error, and How Do I Fix it? Argument #2 ($post) must be of type App\Models\Post, App\Models\User given

Tags: php, laravel, server

I am trying to use a Gate to see if the currently authenticated user matches the user_id column of the "posts" table.

However, when attempting to use the Gate inside my controller, it is giving me the following error, and I am at a loss.

```
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(): Argument #2 ($post) must be of type App\Models\Post, App\Models\User given, called in [path]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 535
```

Thanks.

My Controller:

```
class updatePost extends Controller
{
  public function updatePost(Request $request, Post $post) {

    if (Gate::allows('updatePost', auth()->user(), $post)) {
      $post->title = $request->input('title');
      $post->body = $request->input('body');
      $post->save();
      return redirect()->route('readPost', ['id' => $post->id]);
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
  }
}
```

My Gate:

```
Gate::define('updatePost', function (User $user, Post $post) {
          return $user->id === $post->user_id;
      });
```

Comment: the default first param in the callback function of `Gate::define` is the current user, which you don't need to pass, just use  `Gate::allows('updatePost', $post)` and `Gate::define('updatePost', function (User $user, Post $post){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The define callback always receives the logged in user as first parameter followed but the parameters given by allows().

Try this

```php
if (Gate::allows('updatePost', $post)) {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Quick question. Do I need to create a variable called $post, or is the gate taking in the argument from here:   public function updatePost(Request $request, Post $post)

Comment: It will take it from updatePost, yes.